# clusterMap split list of data.frames

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm working with two lists of data.frames and currently run something similar to this (simplified version of what I'm doing):

```
df1 <- data.frame("a","a1","L","R","b","c",1,2,3,4)
df2 <- data.frame("a","a1","L","R","b","c",4,4,4,4,4,44)
df3 <- data.frame(7,7,7,7)    
df4 <- data.frame(5,5,5,5,9,9)    

L1 <- list(df1,df2)
L2 <- list(df3,df4)

myfun <- function(x,y) {
    difa = rowSums(abs(x[c(T,F)] - x[c(F,T)]))
    difb=sum(abs(as.numeric(y[-c(1:6)])[c(T,F)] - as.numeric(y[-c(1:6)])[c(F,T)])) 
    diff <- difa + difb
    return(diff)
}
output1 <- mapply(myfun, x = L2, y = L1)
```

The same number of data frames are in each list and each dataframe from one list corresponds to the dataframe in the other list. The dataframes in one list contain a single row while the other dataframes in the second list contain a dynamic number of rows; hence the use of sum and rowSums. The number of numeric columns are also dynamic but always the same between corresponding dataframes.

I'm looking to use parallel processing to speed up the computation when dealing with 1-10 million dataframes per list. I tried the following:

```
library(parallel)
if(detectCores() > 1) {no_cores <- detectCores() - 1}
if(.Platform$OS.type == "unix") {ptype <- "FORK"}
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores, type = ptype)
clusterMap(cl, myfun, x = L2, y = L1)
stopCluster(cl)
```

However, due to the significant amount of data I'm using, this will quickly fill up the memory. I assume due to loading the entire lists of data frames in each cluster?? I'm new to parallel processing in R and have read that splitting up the data into chunks according to the number of cores available is required for some parallel functions that don't implement it automatically, so I tried the following which does not work:

```
library(parallel)
if(detectCores() > 1) {no_cores <- detectCores() - 1}
if(.Platform$OS.type == "unix") {ptype <- "FORK"}
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores, type = ptype)
output1 <- clusterMap(cl, myfun, x = split(L2, ceiling(seq_along(L2)/no_cores)), y = split(L1, ceiling(seq_along(L1)/no_cores)))    
stopCluster(cl)
```

Can someone help a newbie out? Most of the information I've been reading about uses parApply/parLapply/etc. I was able to use mcmapply, but since it only uses forking, I cannot use it. My code has to run on both unix and windows systems; hence my  testing for OS.type to set it at fork.

UPDATE: So I think it is working correctly in the sense that it's parsing out chunks to different clusters, but the data type is not playing nice with binary operators inside the clusters. Issue appears to be related to it becoming a list of lists of dataframes and being treated as non-numeric in the clusters.

Comment: What exactly is your `myfun` trying to do? Can you explain it in words?

Comment: @HongOoi myfun calculates the difference between a numeric datatype and calculates multiple types of t-statistic using various parameters that are in the same R environment for a t.test statistical sorting procedure. It places all of the results inside an array and then writes various portions of that array to multiple files, sometime as many as 300,000 individual files depending on the results of the t.tests. The only portion that seems to be not working with the clusters is using the data chunks as numeric data when calculating the differences.